# How to deal (if possible) with non-accepted answers?

Tags: discussion

I think that everyone noticed the problem with questions having at least one good and upvoted answer, but it is not accepted. It is probably due to many reasons, but usually OP created an account only so he could get the answer and he is not logging in ever again.

Is there a way to mark these questions as answered so they won't continuously appear on the main site, convert them to wiki, etc.? Or maybe we have to live with that...

Comment: this is an excellent question to bring up.  i am noticing the same thing.  [example given](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17545/generating-a-high-snr-sinusoide-with-lut-on-a-dsp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a continuing issue, so I'm suggesting that EVERYONE try to look through their questions that have no accepted answer and either accept an existing answer, or give more information to try to get an acceptable answer!

Let's use the last week of <kbd>December, 2015</kbd> to try to make a dent in the unanswered questions pile!!

---

All I can suggest is that we ping the asker by commenting on the question. I'll try to remember to do it when I see things like this.

Comment: i think we need a better solution than that.  can't you "admin" types mark a question so that "Community" will not resurrect it, time and again?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson : I don't see there are any settings for that, but I'll have another dig.

Comment: there might not be.  maybe you higher ranking admins might need to complain to someone even higher at SE.  i dunno.

Comment: "greater fleas have lesser fleas upon their backs to bite'em. And lesser fleas have smaller fleas, and so *ad infinitum.*"

Answer (score 1):

not really a solution but if you are on the dsp page, click "questions" near the upper right of the page, then click the tab "unanswered" this will only display questions without accepted answers or questions where answers don't have any upvotes.